# Making a row of text elements with square colored background

Tags: html, css

By using HTML and CSS only, I would like to make a row of text (single-letter) elements where each letter is both vertically and horizontally centered on a square colored background. Something like this:

[image]

I tried with: http://jsfiddle.net/63PQa/, but the background is not a square and positioning of the letter seems to be slightly off the center vertically even with `vertical-align: middle`.

In addition, I am wrapping this row of elements within a div, and this div is used inside (CSS or HTML) table, so there can't be any funky margin stuff which may affect its vertical centering inside a cell.

I only need to support major modern browsers, e.g. FF, Chrome, Safari 5+, Opera 11+ and IE 9+

Comment: Can you use padding:10px;padding-right:17px;padding-left:17px; for example or are you looking for another solution ?

Comment: @Akinaru, I need these squares to re-size automatically as part of a fluid layout, so I suspect that fixed paddings won't work well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I got it:

```
.square {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: white;
    background: #5bb75b;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height:30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

And, for vertical align of the "try this" text in your jsfiddle:

```
.container {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  // the rest as you have it
}
```

If you can tolerate hard-setting the height and width, that is.  You need `inline-block` to get the browser to obey `height` and `width` on a `span` element.  The `line-height` was needed to get the vertical centering working.

`vertical-align`... I just got rid of it.  Doesn't seem to have any effect after I added `line-height`.

The 30px and 50px are just arbitrary.  As long as the square height/width are bigger than the text, and the container height is bigger than the square height, you should be good.

Comment: That's basically it - though, the `height`, `line-height` and `width` can be set to `1em`, rather than a pixel count, as you're using `em` elsewhere. Using `padding` if you want... err... padding, around the inside of the squares :)

Comment: Yeah, the 30px I just picked at random.  As long as they're the same and bigger than the text...

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier, thank you for the answer, but this makes the row of boxes *not vertically aligned* with the text 'Try this' anymore. And I think this is due to the extra padding around the letters...

Comment: Well you didn't say that was a requirement :)  Added to my answer.